# Satisfying Docker Hub Pull Rate Limit

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerhub

Last year Docker Hub decided it will no longer provide infinite Docker image pulls (see [here](https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limits)). Which sounds somehow reasonable in theory, causes some issues in practice, when you're in a huge company with a finite number of egress IP addresses.

So, I just thought: let's go the proposed way and provide `docker pull` commands with a user account. Even with a free account it should be possible to download 200 images every six hours, which is sufficient for now and can be extended with a paid account.

But that's easier said than done. The following simple Jenkins pipeline:

```
pipeline() {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Docker Pull') {
            steps {
                withDockerRegistry([url: 'https://registry-1.docker.io', credentialsId: '<docker-hub-account>']) {
                    sh "docker pull maven:3.6.3-openjdk-14"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

still causes following error in build log, although login succeeds:

```
[Pipeline] withDockerRegistry
Using the existing docker config file.$ docker login -u <user> -p ******** https://registry-1.docker.io
Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull docker.io/library/maven:3.6.3-openjdk-14
Error response from daemon: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withDockerRegistry
[Pipeline] }
```

So, simple question: what am I doing wrong?

Just to clarify: error first occured simply running `sh "docker pull maven:3.6.3-openjdk-14"`. That's why I added the `docker login` (Jenkins' `withDockerRegistry{...}` line). I'm just confused adding this line doesn't changed anything.

PS: Checking rate limits as described in [this blog post](https://www.docker.com/blog/checking-your-current-docker-pull-rate-limits-and-status/) outputs: `RateLimit-Limit: 200` and `RateLimit-Remaining: 198`.

PPS: There's like a million blog posts how to mitigate that problem by using mirrors of Docker Hub. I like to use the official way, but I'm just not sure how this should work...

Comment: Not quite sure what the issue is: to me the error suggests that you just went over the 200 pulls limit for anonymous or free users. Why would it behave differently, now that you provide credentials of a free user?

Comment: @FritzDuchardt No, I went over the 100 pulls limit for anonymous users. That's why I wanted to login with a user to be eligible of 200 pulls. I'm the only one using this user and as you can see from PS there's 198 pulls left. But it looks like login has no effect on `docker pull` command and I'm wondering if I need to do something else than `docker login`.

Comment: Now I get it - thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are logging into the wrong registry url. The value for Docker Hub in the `~/.docker/config.json` file is `https://index.docker.io/v1/` and is also [documented by Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/docker-workflow/). You can check your current credentials within that pipeline by running something like:

```
pipeline() {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Docker Pull') {
            steps {
                withDockerRegistry([url: 'https://registry-1.docker.io', credentialsId: '<docker-hub-account>']) {
                    sh "cat ~/.docker/config.json"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The credential is just base64 encoded, so you can also decode to see if anything went wrong with the user/pass values. I'd also compare to a normal login you'd seen on a similar linux host.

Assuming the URL is wrong, adjust the registry:

```
pipeline() {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Docker Pull') {
            steps {
                withDockerRegistry([url: 'https://index.docker.io/v1/', credentialsId: '<docker-hub-account>']) {
                    sh "docker pull maven:3.6.3-openjdk-14"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is also a case where the Jenkins DSL may be getting in the way more than helping since you could just as easily run:

```
pipeline() {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Docker Pull') {
            steps {
                sh "docker login -u $user -p $pass"
                sh "docker pull maven:3.6.3-openjdk-14"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! At least it will help with debugging. I'll try it on Monday and hope it works.

Comment: Just a side note: logging in via `-p` flag is insecure. Docker recommends to use `$ cat ~/my_password.txt | docker login --username foo --password-stdin` instead. I'll use this instead of Jenkins DSL.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't solved it for me. Even with `docker login` and correct data in `~/.docker/config.json` pull limit is reached eventually. I'll give `docker.withRegistry` another try but am not full of hope it will work.

Comment: If you can't get Jenkins to work and want to setup a mirror, I've got a project to automate that. https://hub.docker.com/r/regclient/regsync

Answer (score -3):

Here's a non-technical answer...

Pay for it. You're misusing a resource that isn't meant to be given free to large companies. The restrictions are designed to make you pay. Alternatively, run your own registry.

If 'huge companies' (your words) hack around this limit you'll ruin it for the rest of us. As a contractor working on small projects, I rely on Docker's free registry every day. When I work for large banks then I ask them to pay for it, like everyone else who can afford it.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why the login being passed in Jenkins doesn't work.

Comment: I do actually pay for it (so that I can get the private image limit increased, not to increase my downloads), and GitHub, and the other resources I use, along with a commercial license for IntelliJ, windows 10 pro, Adobe creative cloud and Wolfram Alpha. I also donate to a bunch of open-source libs I use regularly.

Comment: I'm all for someone supporting Docker, especially large businesses. But this still doesn't answer the question, and paying Docker money wouldn't fix the fact that the user account they entered didn't seem to apply. And as the OP commented above, they are a paying user.

Comment: The question is entitled, "Satisfying Docker Hub Pull Rate Limit", and the solution to that is to pay for it. You're right, there is a secondary problem in the code the OP posted, and your answer addresses it, but if the title is right then my answer is correct.